# How to save images from server into device internal memory in ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I've tried with most of the cordova file related plugins and finally came up with this code. It's giving success message but they weren't appearing in gallery. Can anyone help with this, please ?

```
    $scope.download = function download(name, contentType, fileLInk) {
ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
  var url = apiServiceBaseUri + fileLInk;
  var targetPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'myapp/' + name;
  var trustHosts = false;
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': tokenType + ' ' + accessToken
    }
  };

  $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
    .then(function(result) {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'File has been downloaded',
      });
      $ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons();
    }, function(error) {
      $ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons();
      if (error.http_status == 401) {
        $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Oops, Session is expired!',
          template: 'Looks like your session is expired or you logged in from someother device.'
        });
        $ionicHistory.clearCache().then(function() {
          $state.go('start.login');
        });
      }
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Sorry, something went wrong during the request!',
        template: error.data.errors[0].message
      });
    });
});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this plugin after file-transfer

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-refresh-gallery
```

and use this function in your success callbeck of file-transfer

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
    .then(function(result) {
     refreshMedia.refresh(targetPath); 
     //some other things
```

**My Working Code**

```
 $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, {}, true).then(function (result) {
               refreshMedia.refresh(targetPath);
               $scope.fullViewImageDownloadSpiner = false;
               tostService.notify('Image Downloaded', 'top');
           }, function (error) {
               $scope.fullViewImageDownloadSpiner = false;
               tostService.notify('Try Again', 'top');
           }, function (progress) {
               // PROGRESS HANDLING GOES HERE
               //  $timeout(function () {
               //     $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
               // })
           });
```

and Set your target path as

```
var filename = url.split("/").pop();
var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + '/Download/' + filename;
```

This plugin updates the image gallery.When you save an image on android device, and image image is not showing up in gallery .This plugin will work

Hope this solve your problem .. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ujjwal kaushik.  Actually, I tried that as well but no luck.

Comment: It's not. Actually, I installed that plugin and added this line in success call. $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
    .then(function(result) {
      refreshMedia.refresh(targetPath); 
    }, function(error) {
       //error goes here
      }
    });

Comment: That is where it is supposed to work ... it is same as mine

Comment: May I know what you set for target path ? I set the path value as :            var targetPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'myapp/' + filename; I think it works with cordova.file.externalDataDirectory but it works only when there is a external memory card in the mobile.